# Using between in loopback like in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, loopbackjs, between

Somebody knows if it is possible to create a query using "between" in loopback?, something similar to this:

```
select ...
 where value BETWEEN column1 and column2
```

because the loopback documentation explains how to use "between", but of this way:

```
{where: {size: {between: [0,7]}}}, // where column between value and value
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community! What have you tried? Seems like it would be fairly straightforward to set up a test. Note that the condition `a BETWEEN b AND c` could be expressed as `a >= b AND a <= c`.  and `a >= b` is equivalent to specifying `b <= a`. Even if loopback doesn't support the syntax you want to use, there's very likely a suitable workaround.

Comment: Thanks, but loopback expects to receive how first parameter a colunm: {colunm: {between: [value,value]}}, but I need to set how first parameter a value {value: {between: [coumn,colunm]}}.

Comment: Because to use this: a >= b AND a <= c, loopback should allow me to use something like this: {where:{value: {gte:colunm}}}.

Comment: I believe your answer helped me, thnks.

Comment: it would be great if loopback supported the construct you asked about. i'm not sure if that feature is available in which version, or where that feature is in the development cycle. I expect you were able to implement workaround to get a SQL query generated that looks something like `... WHERE column1 <= value AND column2 >= value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html#node-api

A where query in loopback in constructed with structure `{where: {property: {op: value}}}` and they say `value is a literal value`

To achieve what you're doing, executing native SQL would be your best bet:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Executing-native-SQL.html

Comment: I agree, but the idea is only to use the loopback structure, because soon they will remove that option in future releases.

Comment: There are certain operations that loopback cannot provide, you can ask the question in their official github repo, that's what i did when i wanted to do a join and sum on related tables and they recommended using raw sql as current version of loopback cannot support that https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2241

Comment: I will do that thnks